# Convert Stacked bar Chart to horizontal Stacked bar chart swift for DGCharts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

i am using  DGCharts https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts but unable to convert it to horizontal stacked Bar chart can some one help me to convert it to Horizontal bar chart

currently it shows me as
[image]

and i want it as below also want to change axis label angle
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried, including any errors you get and on which line. Show a reproducible code, so we can compile and run it.

Comment: you can find source code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BRYD3gSjK2EF6QNoa5pG-1pSTcKqpC_u/view?usp=drive_web

Comment: no thank you, I'm not downloading some unknown file from some unknown site.